# Microsoft Access to SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, database, excel, ms-access, sql-server-express

I'm trying to develop a solution that manages a database of structural materials . So I'm using C# for the solution . Now , I want to connect it with a SQL Database(the structural material database) and I choose to use Microsoft SQL Server Express 2012 .

All the data I need to import to the database is in an Excel worksheet, so I used Access to create this database by importing the excel worksheet .

I have not a lot of experience on databases , so I need a little bit of guidance on how to create my SQL Database from my Access Database so I could connect my C# program on it.

Comment: Why not just [import the Excel file directly into SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)?

Comment: on acess export your database as ".sql" then import it from sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a migration tool that you can use to migrate you Access database to SQL Server

Have a look here

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access v5.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=28763)